# How i can do so that count rows table according to height page or div?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, antd

Framework - ant design

Work thith table component and his attribute pageSize.I set value to pageSize during resize window, but table don't react.

Comment: Congrats your first post. Could you make your question a little bit more specific?

Comment: Please add some code snippet and how this error looks like.

Comment: This question does not seem to have anything to do with `Electron`. Removing tag